# Bash: parse of $${x,y}

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I found that Bash does not expand a brace after $$.

```bash
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.16(1)-release
$ echo $${x,y}
4821{x,y}      #not expanded (though $$ is evaluated.) ---> Why?!?!?!
```

How should I explain this behavior?

I have tried similar patterns as follows. I can understand them.

```bash
$ echo $?{x,y}
0x 0y          #{x,y} is expanded. 
$ echo ${$}{x,y} 
4821x 4821y    #expanded (We should write like this instead of $${x,y}.)
$ echo $PPID{x,y}
               #not expanded (maybe parsed as a variable "PPID{x,y}")
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  `$$-{x,y}` expands to `12345-x 12345-y`.

Comment: `${var}{x,y}` doesn't have the issue (that couldn't possibly go unnoticed).

Comment: I forwarded this to the `bash-help` mailing list.

Comment: FYI: MS WSL ksh93 `93u+m/1.0.0-beta.2 2021-12-17` produces `899x 899y`.

Comment: @Kaz Try: `echo ${$}{x,y}` and compare: `echo $BASH_VERSION{x,y}` with `echo ${BASH_VERSION}{x,y}` !

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub That's different and expected -- brace expansion is done before variable expansion, so `$BASH_VERSION{x,y}` expands to `$BASH_VERSIONx $BASH_VERSIONy`, which expands to nothing (unless you set those variables). But `$$` is self-terminating, so `$$x` should expand to something like `4821x`, not try to treat the `x` as part of the parameter.

Comment: BTW, this only seems to affect `$$`. `$*{x,y}`, `$@{x,y}`, `$#{x,y}`, `$?{x,y}`, `$!{x,y}`, and `$-{x,y}` all work as expected.

Comment: @GordonDavisson This affect all *normal* variables: `$var{x,y}` don't work too and if you try to `: foo; echo $_{x,y}` don't work, but `: foo; echo ${_}{x,y}` work fine.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub That's the same effect as with `$BASH_VERSION{x,y}`, and it's expected and has a very different effect. With `echo $_{x,y}`, it first expands to `echo $_x $_y`, which will print the values of the variables `_x` and `_y` if they exist (or blank if they don't). Similarly, with `echo $${x,y}`, it *should* expand to `echo $$x $$y`, which should print the PID followed by "x" and then again followed by "y" (this differs because the "x" and "y" aren't treated as part of the expansion). But it doesn't do that at all, instead the `{x,y}` part is left unexpanded.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Put it this way: compare the output from `echo $_{x,y}` with that from `echo $_x $_y` -- they're the same. Now compare the output from `echo $${x,y}` with that from `echo $$x $$y` -- they *don't* match. That's the problem.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Try this: `for pre in word '$' '_' '!' '*' '#';do declare "${pre}"{x,y}"=$((cnt++))";done` and read quietly errors. Then you could: `for pre in word '$' '_' '!' '*' '#';do declare -p "${pre}"{x,y};done`...

Comment: @GordonDavisson Looking for all this, you could say:  *if character are legible for variable name, then you have to enclose them using brace*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash performs brace expansions before parameter expansions. Brace expansion does not do a full analysis of the syntax to be able to determine what is a brace expansion or not. It implements a simple rule the sequence `${` is not treated as brace expansion, even if it looks like it.

If `${a,b}` were allowed to produce `$a $b`, it would mean that brace expansion has to analyze, in detail, every single instance of `${...}` syntax, in order to correctly detect brace expansions, and leave alone parameter expansions.

Now, the expansion does kick in if we escape the dollar sign: `\${a,b}`. Then we get `$a $b` (which are not treated as variables). So the real rule is actually subtle: if `${` occurs **where the dollar sign is unescaped**, then the brace is not scanned for race expansion.

This logic is not perfect, and making it perfect is fraught with pitfalls.

You cannot simply allow `$${` because this could be part of a larger syntax which looks like `$$${`, where the first two `$$` are the PID, followed by `${`.

Quick, tell me, should this undergo brace expansion?

```
$$\$$$$$$$$$\$\$$$\$$$$$$$\$$$$$${a,b}
```

Trying to implement complex exceptions to the `${` rule would be a fool's errand. The correct solution would be for brace expansion to earnestly parse the syntax so that it accurately knows what is a braced parameter expansion and what isn't.

The workaround for this and related issues is to distribute one or more characters into your brace expansion.

That is to say:

```
$${a,b} -> {$$a,$$b}
```

Another case: say we have `$a` and `$b` variables that we want to expand, and we write `${a,b}`. That's not supported, and thus, we manually distribute the dollar sign into the brace expansion:

```
${a,b} -> {$a,$b}
```

In other cases we don't have to. If we have two variables `$foobar` and `$foobaz`, then the brace expansion `$fooba{r,z}` will produce `$foobar` and `$foobaz` that then expand. When there is nothing between the `$` and the `{`, we need the workaround of distributing the `$` sign.

For `$$`, other workarounds are possible:

```
"$$"{a,b}  # $$ is expanded inside double quotes, like all params
${$}{a,b}  # The second $ can be braced, like a param name.
```

Comment: Now I can understand ... except for `$$\$$$$$$$$$\$\$$$\$$$$$$$\$$$$$${a,b}`. This example is so attractive. I would like to analyze it from now.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The simple rule in Bash's brace expansion means that we don't have to analyze the example. `{a,b}` isn't expanded because it's preceded by an unescaped `$`.  If brace expansion did a more correct treatment, it would have to analyze everything before the `{a,b}`.  And then after brace expansion, the analysis would have to be done again to actually perform the expansions that were scanned. Those two would have to to match; any discrepancies would end up on StackOverflow again.

Comment: although: `\\\\\\\\\\${a,b}\\\\\\\\\${c,d}` 

Answer (score 3):

Although it looks like a bug, this behaviour appears to be deliberate.

The manpage says (emphases mine):

> Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. It is strictly textual. **Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion** or the text between the braces.
>
> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged. A `{` or `,` may be quoted with a backslash to prevent its being considered part of a brace expression. **To avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string `${` is not considered eligible for brace expansion**, and inhibits brace expansion until the closing `}`.

---

As noted in the comments, the workaround is to use `${$}` instead of `$$`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I must read the man page carefully again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source :

> ```
> #if defined (SHELL)
>       /* If compiling for the shell, treat ${...} like \{...} */
>       if (c == '$' && text[i+1] == '{' && quoted != '\'')       /* } */
>     {
>       pass_next = 1;
>       i++;
>       if (quoted == 0)
>         level++;
>       continue;
>     }
> #endif
> ```

https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/f3b6bd19457e260b65d11f2712ec3da56cef463f/braces.c#L639

An opening brace `{` following a dollar sign `$` gets skipped despite the fact that there is another dollar signs before the preceding one.

Comment: Yes, this is the documented behavior, as pointed out by @jhnc. It doesn't really matter what *precedes* the `${`, expect perhaps to explain why `${` is special-cased in the first place.

Comment: If the documented behavior covers this corner case purposefully, I would expect a clear comment in the source code.